# Unterschied: "vertreten sein" vs "anwesend sein"?

Tags: meaning, standard-german, difference

Ich wäre gern nochmal erklärt gewesen, von dem was der Unterschied zwischen den beiden wäre.
zB in Sätzen:

"Die ganze Musiklandschaft war an meiner Wand vertreten". "Bei der Preisverleihung waren auch Fotografen vertreten". "KFC ist auch vertreten", "Levis ist in Designer Outler auch vertreten".

Wird so überhaupt normalerweise gesprochen?

Comment: Keines der Beispiele enthält "anwesend sein" - weil es nur um das gefühlt falsche "vertreten sein" geht? Warum ist nach eigener Ansicht hier "vertreten sein" falsch bzw. "anwesend sein" richtig?

Comment: "Ich wäre gern nochmal erklärt gewesen" geht leider nicht. Sag dann besser "Ich hätte gern nochmal erklärt bekommen", welches die Entsprechung ist für diese Sprachebene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vertreten sein" beschreibt die Situation, dass ein Vertreter einer bestimmten Gruppe oder Menge anwesend ist. Man weiß also damit automatisch, dass es noch mehr davon gibt und nicht unbedingt alle anwesend sind / sein müssen.

Das ist bei "anwesend sein" nicht der Fall, denn hier hier gibt es keine solche Information, sondern es wird nur ausgesagt, ob etwas/jemand da ist oder nicht (Ja/Nein-Aussage).

"Vertreten sein" ist also weiter gefasst, und es klingt auch recht förmlich. Diese Wendung wird also eher schriftsprachlich oder in Ansprachen verwendet.